# naming convention - need help

Tags: php, javascript, naming-conventions

I am writing different classes for a booking system.
The 1st class I named is **Room** Room has different attributes like SingleRoom, DoubleRoom and DobuleRoom with Baby.
And another Class is named a **Person** which contains name, age etc.

Now a DoubleRoom with allows max 2 adults with or without a baby. And in SingleRoom I am allowed to add only single adult (no baby)

I want to name the methods accoding to best practices.
I need the suggestion for possible methods and there names.

Comment: Have you seen: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#JavaScript ? It basically says: "use Java's conventions ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java )"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332831/php-best-practices-for-naming-conventions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For methods on classes I generally use the "action+property" convention, which is the standard by most developers. For example,

```
<?php

class Room
{
    public function getName() {}
    public function setName($name) {}
    public function addPerson($person) {}
    public function removePerson($person) {}
    public function addChild($child) {}
    // etc
}
```

As you can see, you are stating what you are doing, and then what you are manipulating by that action.

As for the actual name, I more or less always adopt [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).